# How do I pass external signals into Unity scripts?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on building a card game using Unity. Since I plan to integrate some wireless interfaces into the game,  the inputs of this game are the wireless signals collected by external devices, not from neither keyboard or mouse. And I don't know how to pass the signals I collected into the game to control the movement of the piece. I wonder whether I should modify the APIs like Input or EventTrigger to do these?

Comment: Can you provide more information? Are you able to get data from your external input?

Comment: Yes, I get the external input signals from RFID devices, and I plan to convert these signals into bit streams to control the movement of pieces (card) in the game. However, I have no idea how to use these streams to trigger the movement event.

Comment: [With some code's samples would be much easier to help.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) I think you need a middle class between your device API class and your unity's classes. Read data in intervals or async then broadcast them with an event. your unity class can subscribe to it and use the data...